# Print text from a java class method within a .jsp page in reel time

Tags: java, jsp, java-websocket

I'm trying to write the message received from the client connected to the WebsocketServer in a .jsp web page in real time using the onMessage method of java class. Please I need help.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/endpoint")
public class WebSocketServer {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("onOpen::" + session.getId());        
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        System.out.println("onClose::" +  session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        System.out.println("onMessage::From=" + session.getId() + " Message=" + message);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("onError::" + t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: add code for your jsp page as well

Comment: For the jsp page is basic, it just displays the messages sent by the client.